# Integrate SAP GUI with microsoft ldap

Tags: login, active-directory, ldap, sap

What is the best way to integrate SAP login with Microsoft LDAP? I would like to make my users login to the SAP GUI with their windows Active Directory account.

Comment: sorry bout that. Is there a way for me to move it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While its possible, there are some limitations and requesite. This site [here](http://sap10.blogspot.com/2009/07/enable-sap-single-sign-on-on-windows.html) gives you a description of the process.

Regards.